# Mystifying microbenchmark result for stream API on Java 12 vs. Java 8 with -gc true

Tags: java, java-stream, benchmarking, jmh, java-12

As part of my investigation on the difference between using a complex filter or multiple filters in streams, I notice that performance on Java 12 is way slower than on Java 8.

Is any explanation for those weird results? Did I miss something here?

**Configuration:**

- java 8

  - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13)
  - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
- java 12

  - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12+33)
  - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12+33, mixed mode, sharing)
- VM options: `-XX:+UseG1GC` `-server` `-Xmx1024m` `-Xms1024m`
- CPU: 8 cores

**JMH Throughput Results**:

- Warmup: 10 iterations, 1 s each
- Measurement: 10 iterations, 1 s each
- Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
- Units: ops/s

[image: Comparison tables]

### Code

**Stream + complex filter**

```java
public void complexFilter(ExecutionPlan plan, Blackhole blackhole) {
        long count = plan.getDoubles()
                .stream()
                .filter(d -> d < Math.PI
                        && d > Math.E
                        && d != 3
                        && d != 2)
                .count();

        blackhole.consume(count);
    }
```

**Stream + multiple filters**

```java
public void multipleFilters(ExecutionPlan plan, Blackhole blackhole) {
        long count = plan.getDoubles()
                .stream()
                .filter(d -> d > Math.PI)
                .filter(d -> d < Math.E)
                .filter(d -> d != 3)
                .filter(d -> d != 2)
                .count();

        blackhole.consume(count);
    }
```

**Parallel stream + complex filter**

```java
public void complexFilterParallel(ExecutionPlan plan, Blackhole blackhole) {
        long count = plan.getDoubles()
                .stream()
                .parallel()
                .filter(d -> d < Math.PI
                        && d > Math.E
                        && d != 3
                        && d != 2)
                .count();

        blackhole.consume(count);
    }
```

**Parallel stream + multiple filters**

```java
public void multipleFiltersParallel(ExecutionPlan plan, Blackhole blackhole) {
        long count = plan.getDoubles()
                .stream()
                .parallel()
                .filter(d -> d > Math.PI)
                .filter(d -> d < Math.E)
                .filter(d -> d != 3)
                .filter(d -> d != 2)
                .count();

        blackhole.consume(count);
    }
```

**Old fashion java iteration**

```java
public void oldFashionFilters(ExecutionPlan plan, Blackhole blackhole) {
        long count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < plan.getDoubles().size(); i++) {
            if (plan.getDoubles().get(i) > Math.PI
                    && plan.getDoubles().get(i) > Math.E
                    && plan.getDoubles().get(i) != 3
                    && plan.getDoubles().get(i) != 2) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }

        blackhole.consume(count);
    }
```

You can try by yourself by running docker command:

For Java 8:

> docker run -it volkodav/java-filter-benchmark:java8

For Java 12:

> docker run -it volkodav/java-filter-benchmark:java12

**Source code:**

https://github.com/volkodavs/javafilters-benchmarks

Comment: `JDK 1.8.0_181` : is it also an OpenJDK ? Looks like Oracle JDK

Comment: What's the meaning of those numbers?

Comment: yeah, it's OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13)

Comment: Yeah, i did performance tests in [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). Units are ops/s, basically how many times we can iterate through the method.

Comment: no idea, but have you tried running not in a docker image?

Comment: @Eugene not really, but I will. My services running inside docker container

Comment: The Java Version that you used was a free version, Now java have two types of it, right!! You can expect a quick execution in paid, Kind of Marketing style.

Comment: also, isn't there a possibility whether ur version of docker has been optimized for specific version of java (or vice versa)?

Comment: You're comparing two versions of two different JDKs. Have you tried comparing two versions of the same JDK? Or the same version of two JDKs?

Comment: @DonBranson those test run against OpenJDK

Comment: @Ankit It's unlikely. If anything, Java 12 should be more docker-friendly.

Comment: Start by minimizing the test case. Are you sure Docker is not affecting the results?

Comment: Pretty sure `-gc true` in your configuration wrecks it up for jdk12. Forcing Full GC before each iteration is quite likely to throw off GC heuristics. Why do you have that option to begin with?

Comment: Also, why `@Setup(Level.Invocation)`? It seems your workload wants to collect all the pitfalls at once :)

Comment: Thanks for spotting this out @AlekseyShipilev! I'm re-running my tests with your review. Can you share any articles that might explain why it effects java 12, but not (much?) java 8?

Comment: The answer might be too complicated to fit the comment. The difference seems to be real, and there are weird inlining oddities in jdk12 case, as can be seen with -prof perfasm.

Comment: I now think there is a weird interaction between Full GC and concurrent compilations. `-gc true` is not recommended for lots of reasons, this might be a new one. Still digging...

Comment: @BrianGoetz: I put more details into the title after your edit.  Generally the more a title tells you about what you'll find in the question + answer the better.  I think the conclusion here is that  `-gc true` is the real cause of weirdness.  But I'm not a java expert, so pinging you to review my edit in case I got it wrong.

Comment: @PeterCordes All good!

Answer (score 24):

Thanks, everyone for the help and especially to @Aleksey Shipilev!

After applied changes to JMH benchmark, the results look more realistic (?)

**Changes:**

1. Change the setup method to be executed before/after each iteration of the benchmark.

   `@Setup(Level.Invocation)` -> `@Setup(Level.Iteration)`
2. Stop JMH forcing GC between iterations. *Forcing Full GC before each iteration is quite likely to throw off GC heuristics. (c) Aleksey Shipilev*

   `-gc true` -> `-gc false`

*Note: gc false by default.*

**Comparison tables**

Based on new performance benchmarks there is no performance degradation on Java 12 compare to Java 8.

*Note: After those changes, the throughput error for a small array size significantly increased for more than 100%, for a large dataset remain the same.*

[image: result table]

**Raw results**

*Java 8*

```
# Run complete. Total time: 04:36:29

Benchmark                                (arraySize)   Mode  Cnt         Score         Error  Units
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                     10  thrpt   50   5947577.648 ±  257535.736  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                    100  thrpt   50   3131081.555 ±   72868.963  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                   1000  thrpt   50    489666.688 ±    6539.466  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                  10000  thrpt   50     17297.424 ±      93.890  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                 100000  thrpt   50      1398.702 ±      72.820  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                1000000  thrpt   50        81.309 ±       0.547  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel             10  thrpt   50     24515.743 ±     450.363  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel            100  thrpt   50     25584.773 ±     290.249  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel           1000  thrpt   50     24313.066 ±     425.817  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel          10000  thrpt   50     11909.085 ±      51.534  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel         100000  thrpt   50      3260.864 ±     522.565  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel        1000000  thrpt   50       406.297 ±      96.590  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters                   10  thrpt   50   3785766.911 ±   27971.998  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters                  100  thrpt   50   1806210.041 ±   11578.529  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters                 1000  thrpt   50    211435.445 ±   28585.969  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters                10000  thrpt   50     12614.670 ±     370.086  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters               100000  thrpt   50      1228.127 ±      21.208  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters              1000000  thrpt   50        99.149 ±       1.370  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel           10  thrpt   50     23896.812 ±     255.117  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel          100  thrpt   50     25314.613 ±     169.724  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel         1000  thrpt   50     23113.388 ±     305.605  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel        10000  thrpt   50     12676.057 ±     119.555  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel       100000  thrpt   50      3373.367 ±     211.108  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel      1000000  thrpt   50       477.870 ±      70.878  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters                 10  thrpt   50  45874144.758 ± 2210325.177  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters                100  thrpt   50   4902625.828 ±   60397.844  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters               1000  thrpt   50    662102.438 ±    5038.465  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters              10000  thrpt   50     29390.911 ±     257.311  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters             100000  thrpt   50      1999.032 ±       6.829  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters            1000000  thrpt   50       200.564 ±       1.695  ops/s
```

*Java 12*

```
# Run complete. Total time: 04:36:20
    
Benchmark                                (arraySize)   Mode  Cnt         Score         Error  Units
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                     10  thrpt   50  10338525.553 ? 1677693.433  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                    100  thrpt   50   4381301.188 ?  287299.598  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                   1000  thrpt   50    607572.430 ?    9367.026  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                  10000  thrpt   50     30643.286 ?     472.033  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                 100000  thrpt   50      1450.341 ?       3.730  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilter                1000000  thrpt   50       138.996 ?       2.052  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel             10  thrpt   50     21289.444 ?     183.245  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel            100  thrpt   50     20105.239 ?     124.759  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel           1000  thrpt   50     19418.830 ?     141.664  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel          10000  thrpt   50     13874.585 ?     104.418  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel         100000  thrpt   50      5334.947 ?      25.452  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.complexFilterParallel        1000000  thrpt   50       781.046 ?       9.687  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters                   10  thrpt   50   5460308.048 ?  478157.935  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters                  100  thrpt   50   2227583.836 ?  113078.932  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters                 1000  thrpt   50    287157.190 ?    1114.346  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters                10000  thrpt   50     16268.016 ?     704.735  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters               100000  thrpt   50      1531.516 ?       2.729  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFilters              1000000  thrpt   50       123.881 ?       1.525  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel           10  thrpt   50     20403.993 ?     147.247  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel          100  thrpt   50     19426.222 ?      96.979  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel         1000  thrpt   50     17692.433 ?      67.606  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel        10000  thrpt   50     12108.482 ?      34.500  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel       100000  thrpt   50      3782.756 ?      22.044  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.multipleFiltersParallel      1000000  thrpt   50       589.972 ?      71.448  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters                 10  thrpt   50  41024334.062 ? 1374663.440  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters                100  thrpt   50   6011852.027 ?  246202.642  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters               1000  thrpt   50    553243.594 ?    2217.912  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters              10000  thrpt   50     29188.753 ?     580.958  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters             100000  thrpt   50      2061.738 ?       8.456  ops/s
FilterBenchmark.oldFashionFilters            1000000  thrpt   50       196.105 ?       3.203  ops/s
```

Comment: the Invocation -> Iteration was obvious, gc is not; IMO this does not answer the question. I hope Alexey will present his findings

Comment: Yep, I agree with you @Eugene, I have already asked Alexey for an explanation in the comments. I hope he will find time to give more information around it

Comment: Can you explain what’s obvious about it? I mean it’s still a regression? Since this is with less warmup, does it mean 12 takes longer for that? (But then it should be still warmed up?)